# Version store has reached its maximum size

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am attempting to restore a .bacpac file via powershell to sql server.  Sometimes this works fine, other times it fails.

I'm attempting this on a VM running in Azure.

- Windows Server 2016 Datacenter
- 8GB RAM, 2 virtual cores
- SQL Server (Enterprise) 2016

The .bacpac file in question is not particularly large, it's ~8MB.

When it fails, the error I'm getting is:

> Version store out of memory (cleanup already attempted)

This is reflected in the event log as ESENT 623:

> powershell (744) 71424cd2-8bce-47e0-9b60-a9d80ce96316: The version store for this instance (0) has reached its maximum size of 2Mb. It is likely that a long-running transaction is preventing cleanup of the version store and causing it to build up in size. Updates will be rejected until the long-running transaction has been completely committed or rolled back.

I've found out a lot about what causes this error, and how to check the size of the version store, but I haven't found out how to get past it.

I've tried increasing the size of the tempdb data and log files to 64MB and recycling the MSSQLSERVER service prior to restoring the .bacpac but this didn't seem to have any impact.

It stands to reason that if the version store has a max size of 2MB and it's running out of space, that increasing the max size of the version store is what needs to happen, but I can't find anything that says how to do that (or even implies it's possible).

Is it possible to increase the max size of the version store?  If so, how is it done?  If not, what else can I try to get this .bacpac restored correctly?

**UPDATE**
Specific version/edition info requested in comments below:

`2021-08-12 07:51:59.04 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM) - 13.0.1601.5 (X64)  Apr 29 2016 23:23:58  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 6.3 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)`

Comment: Look in the ERRORLOG of your SQL Server instance and post the version and post the version and edition message that's first logged, and this error as it appears in the SQL Server log.

Comment: Just curious, why is your TempDB so tiny? Best practice is to put TempDB on its own dedicated drive, and to pre-grow the files to the size of the drive divided by the number of files, so if TempDB lives on a 10 GB drive and you have 8 data files and 1 log file (as per the default) then each file should be pre-grown to about 1.1 GB. Anyways, I'm unfortunately not familiar with the error you're running into, but perhaps this question is relevant, and if not, still worth looking into.

Comment: @J.D - I'm trying to run automated regression testing against software that is being deployed on a VM that's being created from a pre-existing image.  The image had SQL Server set up the way it is.  Sadly I don't have another disk I can put tempdb on - that was a suggestion I read elsewhere too.  I just don't have the option to try that.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - added that info to the post.

Comment: You're running an unsupported version of SQL Server 2016.  Service Pack 2 is the oldest supported version, and SP2 CU17 is the latest version.  And do you see the error message in the ERRORLOG file.  That would confirm that you've connected to the instance you think you are.  It's unexpected to see that error message from Enterprise Edition.

Comment: I have a newer VM image I can switch to that has SQL Server 2019.  I'll see if that makes a difference.  It's odd that even on the out of date version of SQL Server, the .bacpac restores successfully about half the time.

The ERRORLOG file does not have any messages about the .bacpac restore, even when it's successful.  The first messages I see regarding the database that's been restored are "HkHostDbCtxt::Initialize(): Database ID: [9] 'MY_DATABASE_NAME'", and then "Starting up database 'MY_DATABASE_NAME'." 

When the .bacpac restore fails, there's nothing in the ERRORLOG file about it.

Comment: @wbj Gotcha, well even if you're unable to put TempDB on its own disk, you likely should still allocate more space to it's files upfront. Probably at least 500 MB or 1 GB total (split evenly across each file) if possible. (Note I'm picking a pretty arbitrary number and it really depends on your specific workload, though it's hard to imagine one would need less than 500 MB for their TempDB).